scalability of BFT Algorithm (Blockchain)
what is the maximum number  of transactions that can be handled using BFT Algorithm at a time?
i want to integrate 2 consus algorithm the first one is BFT and when the transactions are a lot and BFT will not be able to handle all of them i will pass these transactions to POA algorithm that could handle scalable amount of transactions .
